# Python script to replace #define values in C file

Tags: python, parsing

I am really really new to Python and I am trying to built a script to change the values of #define variables.
My code seems to work however it ruins the C indentation of the output file.
So how can I workaround the white space problem?
Any suggestion for smarter implementation than mine will be highly appreciated!

```
KEYWORDS=["PERIOD","PWM_RATE","DUTY_OFFSET","MAX_DUTY"]
VALS=[3,3,3,3]    
import re
f1 = open('../src/in.c','r')
f2 = open('../src/out.xc','w')
for line in f1:
    s=line.split()
    if len(s)> 1 and s[1] in KEYWORDS:
        s[2] = VALS[1]
    f2.write(' '.join(s)+'\n')
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of tokenizing the entire source file, you could maybe just use replace in strings, like this:

```
for line in f1:
    for i in range(len(KEYWORDS)):
        line = line.replace("#define " + KEYWORDS[i], "#define " + KEYWORDS[i] + " " + str(VALS[i]))
    f2.write(line)
```

Indeed this would not work on variables that already have values, it would not replace their old values only append to them.

So the solution OP suggested was instead of replacing the string in the line, to simply rewrite the entire line like this:

```
for line in f1:
    for i in range(len(KEYWORDS)):
        if line.startswith("#define") and KEYWORDS[i] in line:
            line = "#define " + KEYWORDS[i] + " " + str(VALS[i])+"\n"
    f2.write(line)
```

Another solution would be to use a regular expression (`re.sub()` instead of `line.replace()`)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry. I have another error, I should have assigned the return value of the replace to the original string, after this it should work, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thanx for the quick response but I still get a define line such as
**#define PERIOD 2      5000000** which will be correct if we somehow delete everything after the "**2**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but there was a missing paranthesis in the line where I do the replace, I fixed it, the code works for me. Sorry for the bugs

Comment: @Dimitris Do you mean if the variable is already defined it won't replace its value?

Comment: Well it just added the **2** but also kept the previous value (aka **500000**).
I changed it a little bit by adding
`if line.startswith("#define"):`
and then rewriting the line instead of just replacing
`line = "#define " + KEYWORDS[i] + " " + str(VALS[i])+"\n"`

Comment: Yes, for it to replace the old value you would need a regular expression, but I see you already marked another answer as accepted so you've got your solution. Yes, I guess your way would work too (if you're guaranteed that there is only one define on each line, which you probably are), I didn't think of it.

Comment: I mostly used yours though! If you edit your post i will accept this one.

Comment: I'm not sure mine was the best solution, but I did edit it. But I had something to add to the condition of rewriting the line so it doesn't replace variables that are not in the KEYWORDS list as well, I hope it's ok.

Answer (score 3):

Use `regex` as it'll maintain the original spacing between the words in the line:

Use `with` statement for handling files as it automatically closes the files for you.

```
with open('../src/in.c','r') as f1, open('../src/out.xc','w') as f2:
    for line in f1:
        if line.startswith("#define"):
            s=line.split()
            if s[1] in KEYWORDS:
                val = str(VALS[1])
                line = re.sub(r'({0}\s+)[a-zA-Z0-9"]+'.format(s[1]),r"\g<1>{0}".format(val),line)
        f2.write(line)
```

**Input:**

```
#define PERIOD  100
#define PWM_RATE  5
#define DUTY_OFFSET  6
#define MAX_DUTY             7
#define PERIOD 2     5000000

#include<stdio.h>  
int main()  
{  
    int i,n,factor;  
    printf("Enter the last number of the sequence:");  
    scanf("%d",&j);
}
```

**Output:**

```
#define PERIOD  3
#define PWM_RATE  3
#define DUTY_OFFSET  3
#define MAX_DUTY             3
#define PERIOD 3     5000000

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i,n,factor;
printf("Enter the last number of the sequence:");
scanf("%d",&j);
}
```

Comment: Well, this code fails without the len(s)>1 which I added but also doesn't replace anything on the new text. Could it be an error on the regex?

Comment: sure! I was still trying different things :-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
replace = {
    'PERIOD': '3'
}

with open('/home/jon/blah.txt') as fin, open('/home/jon/blah2.txt', 'w') as fout:
    lines = (line.strip() for line in fin)
    for line in lines:
        parts = line.split(None, 2)
        if parts[0].lower() == '#define':
            parts[2] = replace.get(parts[1], parts[2])
            fout.writeline(' '.join(parts) + '\n')
        else:
            fout.writeline(line + '\n')
```

So this'll only do lines starting with `#define` - and anything up to the next space is the name to look up, and if found in replacements, will replace the value, otherwise, just leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `.split()` is going to ignore the leading whitespace.

I would use a regexp to capture the leading whitespace and append your output to what it captures:

```
import re
line ='\t#define x'
split = line.split()
begin = re.match('^\s', line)
print(line[begin.start():begin.end()]+' '.join(split))
```